# Read items attachments and write them to local folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, pnp-powershell, attachments

I have this on-premises power shell script which reads SharePoint list attachments and save them to local folder:

```
  $ItemAttachmentURLPrefix =$HeaderListItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix
    $attachmentCollection = $HeaderListItem.Attachments

    $AttachmentSeq = 0
    ForEach($Attachment in $attachmentCollection)
    {
        Write-Host "`tDownloading Attachement: " $attachment $ItemAttachmentURLPrefix
        
        $AttachmentSeq++

        $AttachmentDataObj = "" | Select "Attachment Seq", "JDE Company", "Vendor Number", "Vendor Invoice Number", "Attachment Name", "Attachment System Name", "Job-run Date/Time Stamp"

        $file = $spSourceWeb.GetFile($ItemAttachmentURLPrefix + $attachment)
        $bytes = $file.OpenBinary() 
        $AttachmentFileName = $FilePrefix + "_AP_" + $InvoiceIDFormatted + "_" + $attachment
        $Attachmentpath = $AttachmentFolder + $AttachmentFileName #$FilePrefix + "_*emphasized text*AP_" + $InvoiceIDFormatted + "_" + $attachment
        $fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($Attachmentpath, "OpenOrCreate") 
        $fs.Write($bytes, 0 , $bytes.Length)    
        $fs.Close() 

    }
```

But how can I convert this to PnP PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below PnP PowerShell code to download list item attachments:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev -Interactive

$listitem = Get-PnPListItem -List Employee -Id 2  
$attachments = ForEach-Object {Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $listitem -Property "AttachmentFiles"}  

$attachments | ForEach-Object { Get-PnPFile -Url $_.ServerRelativeUrl -FileName $_.FileName -Path "E:\SharePoint\Documents" -AsFile }
```

**Source**: [Download Attachments From SharePoint List Item Using PnP PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/download-attachments-from-sharepoint-list-item-using-pnp-powershell)

Comment: thanks ,, but how i can mimic `$fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($Attachmentpath, "OpenOrCreate") `? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need to use that. Above code should for you as it is.